# Oracle apex to audit all activities

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

how i can save all user activity like :

1. Logins/Logoffs
   i want to use two authentication schema (SSO,Custom schema) and if user close browser without logout how get logout time .
2. Actions (enter page , and exit page)
3. export data from interactive report using built in download  (csv/pdf/html/email)
4. search in interactive report/grid

i want save any of above action  into database please any advise how do that ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's not a free code-writing service; the idea is to try something, then if you get stuck, we can help.

Comment: A trigger or stored procedure should work nicely for tracking most of these activities.

Comment: thanks alexherm , but how i get download pdf/email/csv action and insert  into table .

Comment: above_c_level, can you tell me what the price and what the services

Comment: @jaw-al no price. in general you have to build something first, then we can help you with specific problems or errors. honestly you could find a lot of the answers you're looking for from online tutorials in APEX.

Comment: Some of this is automatically recorded and available in the APEX_WORKSPACE_ACTIVITY_LOG view. Closing the browser (tab/process/drop off internet connection...) can't be detected. Others may need writing code, but you need to identify a single specific issue for each question for a useful response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actions you mentioned in your requirement#1,2 gets audited by default by apex and is available in table `apex_workspace_activity_log`, you can use calendar component (or some other component) to display your data on UI.
For download activity: you can use the approach explained [here](https://spendolini.blogspot.com/2018/04/logging-apex-report-downloads.html).

Tweaking a bit the logic of download activity, you should be able to accomplish the audits for search on IR/IG.